# Add EventStream of dynamically created object changes to UndoManager

Tags: javafx, reactive-programming, frp, undo-redo, reactfx

Using the [UndoFX library](https://github.com/TomasMikula/UndoFX), I create an UndoManger as follows:

```
EventStream<DocumentChange<?>> changes = document.getChanges();

undoManager =
  UndoManagerFactory.unlimitedHistoryUndoManager(
    changes,
    c -> c.redo(),
    c -> c.undo(),
    (c1, c2) -> c1.mergeWith(c2)
  );
```

The [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX) `EventStream` returned by the document is created by merging a number of EventStreams which are available at document creation.  For example,

```
documentChanges = EventStreams.merge(selectedSymbolChanges, symbolListChanges);
```

However, the document gets items added to it later, and those items include EventStreams that should also be published to the document EventStream.  I've tried

```
documentChanges = EventStreams.merge(documentChanges, newObjectChanges);
```

However, changes in the `newObjectChanges` EventStream never hit the UndoManager.

What is the best way to merge additional EventStreams into the UndoManger after it is already created?  Or is this impossible (i.e., stream must be immutable)?

If the latter is the case, how does one create a stream for a dynamic number of objects that don't exist at UndoManager creation time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this.

1. Create an `ObservableSet` of event streams and use [EventStreams.merge(ObservableSet)](http://www.reactfx.org/javadoc/2.0-M4/org/reactfx/EventStreams.html#merge-javafx.collections.ObservableSet-) to dynamically merge all streams from the set. You can then dynamically add/remove streams to/from the set.
2. Use a `ConnectableEventStream` as a placeholder and later connect it to dynamically obtained streams:

   ```
   ConnectableEventStream<DocumentChange<?>> dynamicChanges =
           new ConnectableEventSource<>();

   EventStream<DocumentChange<?>> documentChanges =
           EventStreams.merge(staticChanges, dynamicChanges);

   // later
   dynamicChanges.connectTo(newObjectChanges1);
   dynamicChanges.connectTo(newObjectChanges2);
   ```

Comment: I went with the latter and it works great.  Thanks both for the solutions and the sweet libraries!  UndoFX has made implementing undo/redo in JavaFX a breeze, especially when leveraging change event merging.